# How to group two fields while creating content type?

Tags: entities, nodes

I wanted to a content type which get number of title and links. And I want an option which allows the user to add more title and links. The fields in the content type are

```
   1. Promotional Image
   2. Image Alternative Text
   3. Title
   4. Links
```

In the above mentioned field. I wanted to group only the Title and Links field. I wanted to give add more option for those two fields alone. Can anyone tell me how this could be done. I cant establish a link between those two fields. At present when I select the 'number of values' option in field settings it gives me add more button to each field but I am not able to link those two fields with any relation. Can anyone please suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group fields together to be accessible as a single field on your form, the easiest way is using the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. It:

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.

Using that you can group your Title and Links fields into one, and you'll have an 'Add more' button for the group, rather than for each individual field widget.

Comment: It worked well. I could use the field collection through UI but I need to create the field collection. but I need to create the entire content type programmatically. I have no problem creating the fields programmatically but field collection doesn work if I do the way I do for other fields.

Comment: [link](http://www.thecarneyeffect.co.uk/creating-custom-content-type-adding-fields-programmatically-drupal-7#comment-32) This is how I create the content type for your kind information.

Comment: Have a look at [Creating field collection programatically](http://drupal.org/node/1106182), it should have all the information you need

Comment: The link you gave me tells us how to create field collection but what is need is how to add fields to this field collection programmatically?

Comment: I dont understand the second part of the code which actually adds the fields to the collection.

Comment: There is no proper explanation in that link. Could you please brief me how this is done?

Comment: I have updated my code in the question. Can you please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this too; [Field Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group):

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers.